# Why does the iteration take so long in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, iteration, hashcode

Hey I'm new with Ruby and I've a Problem. My file Wordlist has over 100.000 words, I want to check with the method test_password if my hashcode is equal to a word from my file Wordlist, but when I check for example for the last word of my file it takes so many time to iterate through it, can please somehone help me how to make it faster?

```
File.open("Wordlist.txt", "r") do |fi|
  fi.each_line do |words|
    text_word << words.chomp
  end
end

text_word.each do |words|
  if test_password(words,ARGV[0])
    puts "FOUND: " + words
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What happens with smaller inputs? Which of the lines takes long?

Comment: You can try posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What does `test_password` do? Is it the first iteration or second which is slow?

Comment: the first Iteration is fast but the second Iteration ist slow, test_password checks if my hashcode which I enter on the command line equals to a word in my file and returns a boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a hash with `[hash_code(word), word]` pairs once, and write the results as JSON, YAML or in a database (e.g. SQLite).
It's okay if it takes a long time to calculate this hash because you'll only have to do it once.
The next times, you only have to read the saved hash, which should be fast.

Checking if a word or a hashcode is inside the hash should be very fast, now.

Here's a small example with TODOs left for you:

```
require 'json'
require 'digest/md5'

hashcodes = {}

def my_hashcode(word)
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest word
end

# This part is slow, that's okay because it can be saved once and for all and doesn't depend on your input
File.open('/usr/share/dict/american-english') do |wordlist|
  wordlist.each do |word| 
    word.chomp!
    hashcodes[my_hashcode(word)] = word
  end
end

#TODO: Write hashcodes to JSON file
#TODO: Read hashcode from JSON file

# This part depends on your input but is very fast:
some_hashcode = my_hashcode("test")

p hashcodes[some_hashcode]
# => "test"

p hashcodes["S0MEWEIRDH4SH"]
# => nil
```